# INSERT values from temp table conditionally into source table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a big INSERT/SELECT statement and I capture two fields via OUTPUT like so:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (
    spam INT,
    eggs INT
);
    
INSERT INTO dest_table ( foo, bar, baz )
OUTPUT
    inserted.foo,
    inserted.bar INTO @temp(spam, eggs)
SELECT
    foo,
    bar,
    baz
FROM
    source_table 
WHERE
    eggs IS NULL;
```

I end up with a big mapping table like this:

```
spam | eggs
-----+------
 1   | 100
 2   | 200
 3   | 300
 4   | 400
```

Now what I need to do is "backfill" this data into the original source table.

I need something like:

```
UPDATE
    source_table
SET
    eggs = ...
WHERE
    eggs IN
    (
        SELECT eggs FROM @temp WHERE spam = source_table.id
    )
```

Comment: Your `@temp` table is a Table-Variable, not a `#TemporaryTable` - just so y'know as you're crossing terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UPDATE` statement is *almost* there, but you want this:

```
UPDATE
    s
SET
    eggs = t.eggs
FROM
    source_table AS s
    INNER JOIN @temp AS t ON s.id = t.spam
WHERE
    s.eggs IS NULL;
```

- Using `INNER JOIN` with `@temp` will filter `source_table` so only relevant rows will be updated, and also means it maps each `source_table` row to a row in `@temp`.
- More examples here: [How do I UPDATE from a SELECT in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server)